# Conditionally format font color based on value from query

Tags: php, css, mysql

I have a completed script that displays store sales results.  Within the results I have multiple params that i need to change the color. The below works for one parameter but how can I get it to do it for multiple criteria?  Say I want to change the TMP but also the bundle and gp smart?

```
<td width="75px" id="profit">'.$data["tmppercent"].'</td>
```

and

```
<td width="75px" id="profit">'.$data["bundlepercent"].'</td>
```

The full script is:

```
 $count = $db->exec($sql);
                $sql = "Select * from BevWhiteboard ";
                $result = $db->query($sql);
                echo "<table class='fixed_header' width='1080'>";
                echo "<thead background='black'>";
                Echo "<th id='man' width='100px'>Employee Name</th>";
                Echo "<th class='model' width='100px'>GP</th>";
                Echo "<th class='desc' width='75px'>Activations</th>";
                Echo "<th class='ingram' width='75px'>Upgrades</th>";
                Echo "<th class='verizon' width='75px'>Smartphones</th>";
                Echo "<th class='mp' width='75px'>GP / Smart</th>";
                Echo "<th class='dpmax' width='75px'>Acc. GP / Smart</th>";
                Echo "<th class='percent' width='75px'>Pullthrough %</th>";
                Echo "<th class='netprofit' width='75px'>TMP %</th>";
                Echo "<th class='netprofit' width='75px'>Bundle %</th>";
                Echo "<th class='netprofit' width='75px'>HUM</th>";
                echo "</tr></thead>";
                echo "<tbody id='imwireless' align='center' border='1'>";

                foreach ($result as $data) {
                    if($data["tmppercent"]<"75"){
                        echo '

                       <tr >
                       <td id="man" width="100px">'.$data["Employee_Name1"].'</td>
                       <td id="model" width="100px">'.$data["GP"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["activations"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["upgrades"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["smartphone"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["gp_smart2"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["accessorygp"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["pullthroughpercent"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px" id="tmp"><font color="red">'.$data["tmppercent"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px" id="tmp">'.$data["bundlepercent"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px" id="profit">'.$data["HUM_Devices"].'</td>
                       ';
                    }  
                    echo '

                       <tr >
                       <td id="man" width="100px">'.$data["Employee_Name1"].'</td>
                       <td id="model" width="100px">'.$data["GP"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["activations"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["upgrades"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["smartphone"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["gp_smart2"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["accessorygp"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["pullthroughpercent"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px" id="profit">'.$data["tmppercent"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px" id="profit">'.$data["bundlepercent"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px" id="profit">'.$data["HUM_Devices"].'</td>
                       ';     
                }
                echo "</tr></tbody></table>";
```

So with the above it returns true if TMP is below 75%.  This works fine.  How can I have it so that if TMP is below 75 its red and if HUM = 0 turn those red and so on.

[image]

As you can see in my image, I used an elseif and it colors the HUM correctly but omits where the first if is.

```
$count = $db->exec($sql);
                $sql = "Select * from BevWhiteboard ";
                $result = $db->query($sql);
                echo "<table class='fixed_header' width='1080'>";
                echo "<thead background='black'>";
                Echo "<th id='man' width='100px'>Employee Name</th>";
                Echo "<th class='model' width='100px'>GP</th>";
                Echo "<th class='desc' width='75px'>Activations</th>";
                Echo "<th class='ingram' width='75px'>Upgrades</th>";
                Echo "<th class='verizon' width='75px'>Smartphones</th>";
                Echo "<th class='mp' width='75px'>GP / Smart</th>";
                Echo "<th class='dpmax' width='75px'>Acc. GP / Smart</th>";
                Echo "<th class='percent' width='75px'>Pullthrough %</th>";
                Echo "<th class='netprofit' width='75px'>TMP %</th>";
                Echo "<th class='netprofit' width='75px'>Bundle %</th>";
                Echo "<th class='netprofit' width='75px'>HUM</th>";
                echo "</tr></thead>";
                echo "<tbody id='imwireless' align='center' border='1'>";

                foreach ($result as $data) {
                    if($data["tmppercent"] <"70"){
                        echo '

                       <tr >
                       <td id="man" width="100px">'.$data["Employee_Name1"].'</td>
                       <td id="model" width="100px">'.$data["GP"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["activations"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["upgrades"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["smartphone"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["gp_smart2"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["accessorygp"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["pullthroughpercent"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px" id="tmp"><font color="red">'.$data["tmppercent"].'%</td>
                       <td width="75px" id="tmp">'.$data["bundlepercent"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px" id="profit">'.$data["HUM_Devices"].'</td>
                       ';
                    }  

                    elseif($data["HUM_Devices"] < "1"){
                        echo '

                       <tr >
                       <td id="man" width="100px">'.$data["Employee_Name1"].'</td>
                       <td id="model" width="100px">'.$data["GP"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["activations"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["upgrades"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["smartphone"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["gp_smart2"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["accessorygp"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["pullthroughpercent"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px" id="tmp">'.$data["tmppercent"].'%</td>
                       <td width="75px" id="tmp">'.$data["bundlepercent"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px" id="profit"><font color="red">'.$data["HUM_Devices"].'</td>
                       ';
                    }  

                    else{
                    echo '

                       <tr >
                       <td id="man" width="100px">'.$data["Employee_Name1"].'</td>
                       <td id="model" width="100px">'.$data["GP"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["activations"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["upgrades"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["smartphone"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["gp_smart2"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["accessorygp"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px">'.$data["pullthroughpercent"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px" id="profit">'.$data["tmppercent"].'%</td>
                       <td width="75px" id="profit">'.$data["bundlepercent"].'</td>
                       <td width="75px" id="profit">'.$data["HUM_Devices"].'</td>
                       ';     
                    }
                }
                echo "</tr></tbody></table>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set up styles for each variable before the `echo` and then you don't need an `if` for each variable. I would also use [heredoc syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) to make it easier to write the output. For example:

```
$tmpstyle = $data["tmppercent"] < "75" ? ' style="color: red;"' : '';
$bundlestyle = $data["tmppercent"] > "50" ? ' style="color: green;"' : '';
$gp_smartstyle = $data["gp_smart2"] < "30" ? ' style="color: blue;"' : '';
echo <<<EOD
    <tr >
    <td id="man" width="100px">{$data["Employee_Name1"]}</td>
    <td id="model" width="100px">{$data["GP"]}</td>
    <td width="75px">{$data["activations"]}</td>
    <td width="75px">{$data["upgrades"]}</td>
    <td width="75px">{$data["smartphone"]}</td>
    <td width="75px" $gp_smartstyle>{$data["gp_smart2"]}</td>
    <td width="75px">{$data["accessorygp"]}</td>
    <td width="75px">{$data["pullthroughpercent"]}</td>
    <td width="75px" id="profit" $tmpstyle>{$data["tmppercent"]}</td>
    <td width="75px" id="profit" $bundlestyle>{$data["bundlepercent"]}</td>
    <td width="75px" id="profit">{$data["HUM_Devices"]}</td>
EOD;
```

Note that you have multiple elements with the same `id` value, this is not supported and you will need to add an index to them to make them unique. For example, add a counter:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($result as $data) {
     ...
     echo <<EOD
<td id="man$i" width="100px">{$data["Employee_Name1"]}</td>
     ...
EOD;
     $i++;
}
```

Comment: I did change all my class names so I have no duplicates for future-proofing my work

Comment: @DavidMorin good idea - you will definitely thank yourself later! :-)